# I am trying to add a Sitemap.xml to React app

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sitemap

I am trying to add a Sitemap.xml file to a vite-react app which is hosted on Netlify so that it gets listed on google . While submitting it in google search console , it keep throwing an error that `Sitemap contains HTML make sure that it is in XML format`

[image: this is my Sitemap.XML]

[image: My folder structure]

and for more details it is saying `Line 2 contains HTML tag`   I guess it might be reading the index.html file as a sitemap I don't know how **but my sitemap is XML format** .

I have tried few Youtube tutorials  but no result

Comment: You need to put your sitemap.xml file into your public directory. Which will not be processed by Webpack and directly copied to your dist folder. You can check your XML at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Answer (score 0):

The sitemap isn't detected and you need to put it into the public directory.
You can also check if it is really there by doing `/sitemap.xml` and see it if loads the correct file.

Next to that you can force Search console to redo a check and it sometimes still bugs you that is isn't correct but let it do its thing for a while and the errors go away.

Comment: Is a sitemap really needed ? I have seen some articles where they are saying that if your website is less than 500 pages it does not need a sitemap.xml

Comment: It helps with indexing